# How SIGINT Researchers/Operators collect, decode and monitor a vast array of wireless data?

Tags: wireless, information-gathering

In wireless communication, data flows at various frequencies ranging from Radio to Satellite communication. These frequency carriers are allocated for different uses based on various requirement parameters such as distance, accuracy, the volume of data, and more.

I am playing with cheaper RTL-SDR receiver to collect radio communication and ADS-B receiver to gather ADS-B data. From my current understanding, at one time 1 wireless receiver can collect data at 1 frequency only (say 100 MHz).

I want to understand how SIGINT (Signal Intelligence) people (like from Intelligence Agencies) work with this vast array of data.

So basically my questions are:

1. How they physically collect it?
2. How do they decide the information collected at a particular frequency is interesting? If yes then how they analyze it? (Here for analysis, my guess is Cryptanalysis)

Comment: How they physically collect it? Or how they make sense of it? Your question seems a bit unclear to me.

Comment: Sorry for being vague. I wanted to ask both. How they physically collect it? and how they decide the information collected at a particular frequency is interesting? If yes then how they analyze it? Thanks for pointing out. I will update the question.

Comment: *"From my current understanding, at one time 1 wireless receiver can collect data at 1 frequency only (say 100 MHz)."* Consider that different systems use different modulations and different RF bandwidths. Broadcast AM is about 10 kHz. Broadcast FM is 300 kHz or so (try setting a digital-tuner FM radio 50-100 kHz off frequency and see what happens). Analog TV around 6 MHz. WiFi 20-40 MHz IIRC. These are just a few examples off the top of my head. Now, other than the detail of the actual transmit frequency, what *technically* keeps that WiFi receiver from picking up a few thousand AM stations?

Comment: @aCVn You are right. The transmitter can send data at any particular frequency between its frequency bandwidth using any modulation method (example for FM Radio, frequency bandwidth is 88-108 MHz & Broadcast band is 30kHz). However, if we are using one receiver then in-order to monitor and capture the traffic, the receiver will need to jump between all the possible frequencies present in bandwidth range (for example in round-robin fashion with a short amount of time dedicated to listening on each frequency). By this, we can detect at what frequency FM stations are running. [continued]

Comment: But we cannot capture whole data as it is of particular FM station and will loose most of the data since receiver won't be listening constantly at one frequency for a long duration. Since receiver will be Hopping on various frequencies, at any moment of time, it will be listening at only 1 particular frequency/FM station. Also, consider the case if a large number of FM stations are running (let's say more than 10). My understanding is for SIGINT Intelligence agencies must be monitoring all carrier frequencies (for example all Satellite Frequency bands and Naval Communication bands).[continued]

Comment: Hence, having 1 receiver hopping on various stations in a particular bandwidth is not worthwhile because the aim of SIGINT is not to find out transmitter stations, rather capture all the traffic, decode and analyze it.

Comment: I think this is way too broad. Multiple methods are used. The techniques to intercept private satellite communications will be vastly different from their techniques to passively monitor Wi-Fi signals of a target during recon, which itself will be vastly different from the techniques used to monitor a potential bespoke RF communication protocol for a bomb. And the way it's analyzed differs even _more_.

Comment: *"Since receiver will be Hopping on various frequencies, at any moment of time, it will be listening at only 1 particular frequency/FM station."* That's not how a radio receiver works. Also, you are conflating the *displayed tuned center frequency* with *the receiver bandpass coverage*. If what you describe was how a radio receiver actually worked, many real-world modulation schemes (certainly AM and FM) would in practice be impossible because the momentarily transmitted frequency changes continuously. Look up how AM and FM look in the frequency domain if you don't understand why that is so.